# jquery animate position in percentage

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, toggle, percentage

how do I determine the positions in percentages?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").toggle(function(){
        $("#slide").animate({top:-100%},1000);
      },function(){
        $("#slide").animate({top:0%},1000);
      });
    });
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").toggle(function(){
        $("#slide").animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
      },function(){
        $("#slide").animate({top:'0%'},1000);
      });
    });
```

Add quotes. (I used single quotes, but js doesn't care if it is ' or ")

Comment: @LGVentura the rule: if there is whatever else then numbers in .animate() or .css() (the first two I think o perhaps there are more) values, use quotes.